# no viable alternative at character ']' when updating columnfamily

Tags: c#, cassandra, fluentcassandra

I'm new to Cassandra, but am trying to update a column family to have secondary indexes on some of the columns.  After creating my column family, I run the following line of code:

```
db.ExecuteNonQuery("UPDATE COLUMN FAMILY Targets with comparator = UTF8Type and column_metadata=[{column_name: Age, validation_class: UTF8Type, index_type: KEYS}];");
```

The problem is I get the following error:
**line 1:141 no viable alternative at character ']'**

I can run that exact statement using the CLI without any issues.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like I need to use CQL when running ExecuteNonQuery: http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.8/dml/using_cql